# How do you eval() a PHP code through multiple levels?

Tags: php, eval

I have this code:

```
$layout_template = template_get("Layout");
$output_template = template_get("Homepage");
$box = box("Test","Test","Test");
eval("\$output = \"$layout_template\";");
echo $output;
```

In the $template_layout variable is a call for the 
variable $output_template, so then the script moves onto the $output_template variable

But it doesn't go any further, inside the $output_template is a call to the variable $box, but it doesn't go any further than one level

Comment: Every time you call eval() an angel dies.

Comment: As a general rule, you do NOT use eval();
There are some valid reasons for eval, but they are few and far between.

Comment: @Aiden: And if you call `eval()` within a loop that's an angel genocide!

Comment: What do you use instead of eval then?

Comment: in your case a simple include should be sufficient ...

Comment: If you use eval, you're doing it wrong. Eval is the opening for numerous sloppy coding practices, numerous security vulnerabilities, and can't be cached by the engine.

Answer (score 2):

I would **never** want nested `eval()`, and especially not in any recursive logic. Bad news. Use [PHP's Include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) instead. IIRC `eval()` creates a new execution context, with overhead whereas `include()` doesn't.

If you have buffers such as:

```
<h1><?php echo $myCMS['title']; ?></h1>
```

I sometimes have files like `Index.tpl` such as above that access an associative array like this, then you just do in your class:

```
<?php
   class TemplateEngine {
       ...
       public function setvar($name, $val)
       {
            $this->varTable[$name]=make_safe($val);
       }

       ....
       /* Get contents of file through include() into a variable */
       public function render( $moreVars )
       {
           flush();
           ob_start();
           include('file.php');
           $contents = ob_get_clean();
           /* $contents contains an eval()-like processed string */
           ...
```

Checkout [ob_start() and other output buffer controls](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

If you do use `eval()` or any kind of **user data inclusion**, be super safe about sanitizing inputs for bad code.

It looks like you are writing a combined widget/template system of some kind. Write your widgets (views) as classes and allow them **to be used in existing** template systems. Keep things generic with `$myWidget->render($model)` and so on.

I saw this on the PHP doc-user-comments-thingy and it seems like a bad idea:

```
<?php
$var = 'dynamic content';
echo eval('?>' . file_get_contents('template.phtml') . '<?');
?>
```

Perhaps someone can enlighten me on that one :P

Comment: @stereofrog - functionally maybe, but speed?

Comment: @sterofrog, what ... file_get_contents() does have the I/O overhead,just in a different place.